# Connecting Lines with Stack Bar

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I could able to generate the following stackbar with lines connection as follows by using kendo-ui:

[image]

```
categoryAxis: {
        categories: ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"],
        axisCrossingValues: [0, 0, 10, 10],
    },
    tooltip: {
        visible: true,
        format: "{0}%",
        template: "#= series.name #: #= value #"
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mskjbLwx/14/

However, I would like to connect the lines with bars as follows. Is it possible to do that in Kendo-UI? The key feature here is that lines does not go in the middle of stackbar, it connects to the edges.

If not possible in Kendo-UI, could be done in d3 library or what is recommended?

[image]

Comment: Almost nothing graph-drawing-related is impossible with d3.js; it's a matter of it not being a *graphing* library and instead being a *graph-drawing* (nee, *visualization*) library, which are different things entirely.

Comment: I'm removing the D3 tag as this is not a D3 question as it currently is. If you want to implement this in D3, please post what you have tried and what you're struggling with.

Comment: Maybe this could be possible with this [Custom Visuals](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/bar-charts/visuals) of [drawning module](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/drawing/multi-path).